# How CDN works in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, cdn

I am aware about the CDN and configuring it into Magento 2 from system configuration.

I just want to know how CDN works internally in magento codebase?

As I am developing an module to upload the product images from website fronend so how will they reflect?

Is there any cron works behind it to serve the images on CDN server?

Is there any command to flush CDN cache (depend on CDN type)?

or any code snippet for work around?

Answer (score 0):

there are no any specific CDN code, only base url to fetch files from remote CDN server.
if CDN dont have files it will send request back to media base path configured in CDN to take file from your server and store it in its own cache.

so your shop works as usuall just different base url for media.
or you can upload/sync your files directly to CDN server storage, like Amazon S3, and work from there... etc.